# Select Value from Dictionary if Key exists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary where I have a `List` as value. I want to select specific elements from the list that belongs to a specific key. I tried this so far:

```
Dictionary<int, List<bool>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<bool>>();
dic.Add(1, new List<bool> { true, true, false });
var works = dic.Where(x => x.Key == 1).SingleOrDefault().Value.Where(x => x == true).ToList();
var doesNotWork = dic.Where(x => x.Key == 2).SingleOrDefault().Value.Where(x => x == true).ToList();
```

The first LINQ works because there is a key equal to 1. Thus I get a `List<bool>` with two elements.
The second LINQ does not work because Value is `null`. How can I rewrite that LINQ such that if there is no suitable key in the dictionary I get an empty `List<bool>`?

I thought my approach would work because I thought the default element had an empty list instead of null as Value.

Comment: why not try to get value from dictionary using `Dictionary.TryGetValue()`?

Comment: `Take(1)` will return one item or an empty enumeration. Is this what you want? `var doesNotWork = dic.Where(x => x.Key == 2).Take(1).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();` But when LINQ gets that hard for me to parse, I do it in regular C# instead.

Comment: Use the dictionary ContainKey() method.

Comment: If you are on C# 6.0 you can use the null-conditional operator and get something like this `dic.Where(x => x.Key == 2)?.SingleOrDefault().Value.Where(x => x == true).ToList() ?? new List<Bool>();` I can't test this since I am not on c# 6.0 but I believe it should work based on [this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) and [this github post](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) shows the `?.` being used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer: This only works on C# 6.0 and later (VS 2015+)**

If you really want to do it in a single line using linq you can use the `?.` operator (null-conditional operator) and get a line like this:

`var shouldWork = dic.Where(x => x.Key == 2)?.SingleOrDefault().Value.Where(x => x == true).ToList() ?? new List<bool>();`

This will set shouldWork to either the result of the linq query or an empty list. You can replace `new List<bool>()` with anything you want

See [MSDN post here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) and [Github post here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) for information on the new features in C# 6.0 specifically this example from the github site:

> int length = customers?.Length ?? 0; // 0 if customers is null

and description of how it works

> The null-conditional operator exhibits short-circuiting behavior,
>   where an immediately following chain of member accesses, element
>   accesses and invocations will only be executed if the original
>   receiver was not null

**Edit:** Since ?. checks for null, you could simplify the above linq query to this:

`var shouldWork = dic[key]?.Where(x => x == true).ToList() ?? new List<bool>();`

where key is some variable holding your key

Comment: This works great. Are there any disadvantages though to using the other possible solutions?

Comment: From what I read it is pretty much syntactic sugar and breaks down into the same code when it is compiled. I don't know this with 100% certainty though

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using LINQ to find a key in a `Dictionary` - the `Dictionary` has more efficient methods for doing that - `ContainsKey`/ indexer pair or more optimal `TryGetValue`.

For instance:

```
int key = 2;
```

(A)

```
var result = dic.ContainsKey(key) ? dic[key].Where(x => x == true).ToList() : new List<bool>();
```

(B)

```
List<bool> values;
var result = dic.TryGetValue(key, out values) ? values.Where(x => x == true).ToList() : new List<bool>();
```

Comment: You say I should not be using LINQ however in your answer you are using LINQ.

Comment: I meant for the **key** part - LINQ is ok for the rest.

Comment: OK for rest?  Why dic[key].Where(x => x == true).ToList() ?   Uh, dic[key] returns the value.

Comment: Yep. The dictionary can do that much more efficient than `Where(...).SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Typo in the 2nd solution 0 should be )

Answer (score 1):

Why does it need to be LINQ?

```
List<bool> works1 = dic.ContainsKey(1) ? dic[1] : new List<bool>();
```

Comment: This will use `.Contains()` twice. :)

Comment: @mwilczynski So, that is an 0(1) operation.

Comment: That's unnecessary check still. :)

Comment: @mwilczynski So, it is not 3 lines.  And again 0(1).   If (!found) is an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use `Dictionary<T>.TryGetValue` so that you don't check twice for a value, ie:

```
        Dictionary<int, List<bool>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<bool>>();
        dic.Add(1, new List<bool> { true, true, false });

        List<bool> match = null;
        var found = dic.TryGetValue(2, out match);
        if (!found) match = new List<bool>();
```

Comment: And what's make you think I think of 2 as a value? He wanted a working solution for missing key, that is `2` is non-existent key here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dictionary<int, List<bool>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<bool>>();
dic.Add(1, new List<bool> { true, true, false });
var works = !dic.ContainsKey(1)? new List<bool>(): dic[1].Where(x => x == true).ToList();
var doesNotWork = !dic.ContainsKey(2) ? new List<bool>(): dic[2].Where(x => x == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a strange result, but anyway this code help you:

```
 var reslt = (dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 2).Value ?? new List<bool>(0))
.Where(x => x)
.ToList();
```

Using method SingleOrDefault() isn't correct, because key in Dictionary is unique.

And x=>x==true is strange too.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know why it need to be LINQ, but this could be a option:

```
var nowItWork = dic.Where(x => x.Key == 2).SelectMany(x => x.Value).Where(x => x).ToList();
```